# Data Binding for ListBox ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm having trouble setting up an automatic binding.

I have a simple WPF application with two classes - `MovieInfo` (contains information about movie files on my filesystem) and a `MediaScanner` class that just returns a `List<MovieInfo>`.  In my MainWindow.xaml, I have a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="242" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" d:ItemsSource="{Binding MovieList}"/>
```

Also in the XAML added to the `<Window ...>` is

```
Name="MainWindow1"
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow1}"
```

In the code behind, I made a public property of the `MainWindow : Window`:

```
public ObservableCollection<MovieInfo> MovieList { get; set; }
```

In the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = this;
    MovieList = new ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>();
    InitializeComponent();
    //this doesn't do anything for me
    //listBox.ItemsSource = MovieList; 
}
```

I have a button that calls:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scanner = new MediaScanner();
    MovieList = new ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>(scanner.ScanAll().OrderBy(x => x.Title));
    //listBox.ItemsSource = MovieList;
    
}
```

It's my understanding that this should take care of everything, yet the `ListBox` won't populate unless I uncomment the `listBox.ItemsSource = MovieList;` where it is in the button_Click.

What am I missing?

Comment: You set the binding in xaml for design time with the prefix `d:`. Remove it and it will also work for runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListBox` does not bind the `MovieList` at runtime [because you prefixed `ItemsSource` with `d`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2022#design-time-data-basics).

> After adding the namespaces, you can put `d:` in front of any attribute or control **to show it only in the XAML Designer but not at runtime.** [...]
>
> You can use `d:` with attributes for any UWP or WPF .NET Core control, like colors, font sizes, and spacing. You can even add it to the control itself.

These namespaces are defined on your XAML root element.

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

In order to make the binding work at runtime, remove the `d:` or add another `ItemsSource` without the `d:` prefix so that you have different sources for design and runtime.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="242" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" ItemsSource="{Binding MovieList}"/>
```

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="242" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" d:ItemsSource="{Binding DesignTimeMovieList}" ItemsSource="{Binding MovieList}"/>
```

Another issue is that you neither implement a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0) for your movie list collection nor [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). In practice this means although you assign a new collection to the `MovieList` property in your button click event handler, the binding does not get notified of the change and will still use the old collection instance. Of course `listBox.ItemsSource = MovieList;` would work here, but it assigns the collection directly and overwrites the binding, so this is a different solution.

In the long run, you should probably apply the MVVM pattern and separate the data to be bound in a view model that implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which solves your issue and at the same time separates your view and your logic and data that are then connected via bindings.

---

Example of a dependency property for your window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<MovieInfo> MovieList
   {
      get => (ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>)GetValue(MovieListProperty);
      set => SetValue(MovieListProperty, value);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty MovieListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(MovieList), typeof(ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public MainWindow()
   {
      DataContext = this;
      MovieList = new ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>();
      InitializeComponent();
      // ...other code.
   }
   
   private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var scanner = new MediaScanner();
      MovieList = new ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>(scanner.ScanAll().OrderBy(x => x.Title));
   }
   
   // ...other code.
}
```

---

Example for a view model in case you want to move to MVVM.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private ObservableCollection<MovieInfo> _movieList;

   public ObservableCollection<MovieInfo> MovieList
   {
      get => _movieList;
      set
      {
         if (_movieList == value)
            return;

         _movieList = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   // ...other code.

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

---

As a final remark, you should consider reusing the `ObservableCollection<MovieInfo> MovieList` instead of creating and assigning a new one each time. This type of collection provides change notifications for adding, removing and replacing items, which will automatically be reflected in the user interface. Exposing an observable collection, but instead of modifying, replacing it, is pointless. If a collection is always replaced, a simple `List<T>` will do the same.

Comment: Ok, so that solved my initial issue --> adjusting public ObservableCollection get/set, and adding a DependencyProperty as you described.   I will move to MVVM when I understand it better-- but why does my initial implementation (as gleaned from tons of sites) not work by itself?

Comment: @papashou It does not work by itself because bindings need to get notified when the bound value changes, otherwise it does not know when to update. However, it does know the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and how to handle its `PropertyChanged` event. Dependency properties have their own notification mechanism that also works with bindings, but those are only implemented on UI elements.

Comment: @papashou Furthermore, the sites you are referring to probably bound the `ItemsSource` (without `d:`) to `MovieList` and they assigned a collection instance **once** in the constructor before `InitializeComponent();`. They did **not assign a new collection**, but just added and removed items from it. That is what an `ObservableCollection<T>` is for, it provides collection change notifications in case it is modified.

Comment: Should I be adding/removing to and from instead?  I am still very new to C# I think I started in early December 2021, so... trying to learn as much as I can!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @papashou It is up to you and your requirements. Both is possible. If you often modify a list use `ObservableCollection<T>`, e.g. you can add or remove movies in the user interface by buttons. If you completely reload lists and they are read-only in the UI, maybe replacing a `List<T>` is the better choice.

Comment: I am doing both.  This is just a part of a conversion of several python scripts I had written but wanting to do a UI.  Scan All will replace the list, while I want to add other functions to modify or remove information.  Thanks, very helpful!